# Why doesn't opencv report width and height of a IplImage* correctly?

Tags: opencv, avi

I got the reference image of a video(.avi) so the the width and height of the image must be as the same as the width and height of the video is and it is.

(my video is a `CvCapture*` and my image is a `IplImage*`)

Width is 1280 and height is 960;

But when I told OpenCV that if the coordinate of a pixel is in the specific rectangle then do something. All of the width of the image was the width of that rectangle.

```
const int Y1 = 430, Y2 = 730, X1 = 0, X2 = 1279 ;
for (int i = Y1; i <= Y2; i++)
    for (int j = X1; j <= X2; j++)
        CV_IMAGE_ELEM(frame_BGR, uchar, i, j) = 255;
```

But only near 1/5 of the width of the page is now white! Then I `X2 = 3000`. Then all of the width of the image is now white and silly thing is that when I change `X2 = 10000` then code didn't report `SEGMENTATION FAULT`.

Why the width-reporting is not working correctly?

I run it on both Ubuntu - g++ and and Windows 7 - visual studio 2010. I think my resolution is high. I know that the video is taken by a Nokia 5800 cellphone. It is so important for me, so excuse me if I was very specific!

Comment: Looks like your image is RGB and you're using CV_IMAGE_ELEM incorrectly, which is why you only see one third of the image being set to white.

Comment: There is still another problem: when I said `if (dots[i].x >= x1 && dots[i].x <= x2 && dots[i].y >= y1 && dots[i].y <= y2)` it still consider the 1/5 of the width! dots is a `vector<CvPoint>`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If the image isn't single channel , you are using  `CV_IMAGE_ELEM` wrongly

It has to be  `pixel = CV_IMAGE_ELEM( frame_BGR, uchar, row_number, col_number * 3 + color_channel );`

So for BGR:

```
uchar blue = CV_IMAGE_ELEM( frame_BGR, uchar, row_number, col_number * 3 + 0 );
uchar green = CV_IMAGE_ELEM( frame_BGR, uchar, row_number, col_number * 3 + 1 );
uchar red = CV_IMAGE_ELEM( frame_BGR, uchar, row_number, col_number * 3 +  2);
```

Really CV_IMAGE_ELEM isn't really worth the effort, you might as well just use frame_BGR.ptr(row) to get a pointer to the start of the row and then increment the pointer to give you B,G,R along the row.